# Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates

Tags: react-native, expo

1. As Im new with React native, Can anyone understand the problem im having here. And if so do give a solution

   import React from 'react';
   import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
   import { ListItem, Badge, Text } from 'native-base';

   const CategoryFilter = (props) => {

   ```
   return(
       <ScrollView
           bounces={true}
           horizontal={true}
           style={{ backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2" }}
       >
           <ListItem style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0, borderRadius: 0 }}>
               <TouchableOpacity
                   // Here the key is different
                   key={1}
                   onPress={() => {
                       props.categoryFilter('all'), props.setActive(-1)
                   }}
               >
                   <Badge
                       style={[styles.center, {margin: 5},
                           props.active == -1 ? styles.active : styles.inactive
                       ]}
                   >
                       <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>All</Text>
                   </Badge>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               {props.categories.map((item) => (
                     <TouchableOpacity
             // Here the key is also different
                     key={item._id}
                     onPress={() => {
                         props.categoryFilter(item._id.$oid), 
                         props.setActive(props.categories.indexOf(item))
                     }}
                 >
                     <Badge
                         style={[styles.center, 
                           {margin: 5},
                           props.active == props.categories.indexOf(item) ? styles.active : styles.inactive
                         ]}
                     >
                         <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                     </Badge>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
               ))}
           </ListItem>
       </ScrollView>
   )
   ```

   }

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   center: {
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center'
   },
   active: {
   backgroundColor: '#03bafc'
   },
   inactive: {
   backgroundColor: '#a0e1eb'
   }
   })

   export default CategoryFilter;

I guess the problem im having is in toucAbleOpacity but the keys are different in both components still it's giving the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pauline is right. To add remove the first key it is not necessary and make sure item._id is a unique string and not an array or some other data type. The revised code looks like this

```
const CategoryFilter = (props) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView
      bounces={true}
      horizontal={true}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2" }}
    >
      <ListItem style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0, borderRadius: 0 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            props.categoryFilter("all");
            props.setActive(-1);
          }}
        >
          <Badge
            style={[
              styles.center,
              { margin: 5 },
              props.active === -1 ? styles.active : styles.inactive,
            ]}
          >
            <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>All</Text>
          </Badge>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {props.categories.map((item) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={String(item._id)}
            onPress={() => {
              props.categoryFilter(item._id.$oid);
              props.setActive(props.categories.indexOf(item));
            }}
          >
            <Badge
              style={[
                styles.center,
                { margin: 5 },
                props.active == props.categories.indexOf(item)
                  ? styles.active
                  : styles.inactive,
              ]}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{item.name}</Text>
            </Badge>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </ListItem>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: I appreciate both of you guys for your help... but the problem still remains :(

Comment: Edited the code slightly, please try now with the new code @Abubakarkhalid and if it still does not work then please share the complete data of the `props.categories`. This categories prop is being passed from the parent which may have the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the key to a specific value in your map, not a array with 2 objects. The item._id seems to be an array with 2 objects. So instead do item.name maybe?

Comment: Yes I have tried that but unfortunately same warning

Comment: Remove the first key you dont need it.